# Check multiple lines of an array against a condition

Tags: .net, arrays, vb.net

Can I reduce something like this:

```
If Line(1) = False _
   AND Line(1) = False _
   AND Line(2) = False _
   AND Line(3) = False _
   AND Line(4) = False _
   AND Line(5) = False _
   AND Line(6) = False _
   AND Line(7) = False _
   AND Line(8) = False _
   AND Line(9) = False Then
```

To something like this:

```
If Line(1-9) = False Then
```

If so, how?

Comment: `Select Case` statement with `Case Else` may sufficent if you want to set statement outside `Line(n)` conditions.

Comment: You should almost always use `AndAlso` and `OrElse` in VB.NET in preference to `And` and `Or`.  If you aren't sure which to use, use the former. If you want to learn the difference (which you should) then read the documentation.

Answer (score 4):

You can use LINQ for that. Assuming `Line` is `List(Of Boolean)`, you can use the LINQ's `All()` function to check all items of the array against a condition:

```
If Line.All(Function(x) x = False) Then
```

If you want to only check the first 9 items, use the `Take` function first:

```
If Line.Take(9).All(Function(x) x = False) Then
```

And if you want to check some items in the middle of the list (not at the beginning of the list), use the `Skip` function firs and then the `Take` function:

```
If Line.Skip(3).Take(9).All(Function(x) x = False) Then
```

Comment: It's a small thing but, given that I would always use a `Boolean` variable directly rather than compare it to `True`, i.e. I would use `Function(x) x` rather than `Function(x) x = True`, I would also use `Function(x) Not x` rather than `Function(x) x = False`.

Comment: @jmcilhinney I would do the same, but just wanted my answer to be clear to the OP, similar to the `Line(1-9) = False` in the question ;). In fact I wouldn't even use `Function(x) Not x`, in that case I'd use `Any()` instead of `All()`, so `Not Any(Function(x) x)`. I like negating one final result instead of each value :).

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively using Array method TrueForAll:-

```
Dim BooleanArray() As Boolean = {False, False, etc... }

If Array.TrueForAll(BooleanArray, Function(fnTest) fnTest = False) Then
Debug.WriteLine("All FALSE")
End If
```